# Is there a way to hyperlink a command button from the chioce made in a combo box?

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to hyperlink a command button from the choice made in a combo box?
I have several PDF documents I want the command button to open. I want to tell the command button where to open the document depending on the selection of the combo box.

Comment: Check the *Application.FollowHyperlink Method* in Access' help system to see whether it suits your need.  If it doesn't, please show us an example combo value.

Answer (score 0):

if your ComboBox contains in a Column the complete file name of your PDF files, in the OnClick event of your Button you can use:

Note: The first Column has Number 0, the second 1 and so on.

```
Dim LocalURL as String
LocalURL = ComboBox.Column(x)
If Dir$(LocalURL) <> "" and UCase$(Right$(LocalURL,4)) = ".PDF" then Application.FollowHyperlink LocalURL
```

This will open the file with the predefined App for PDF files.